# Is it possible to just view files content when traverse NERDTree?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I can traverse NERDTree, but to see file content I press *go*, and once opened file's buffer stays open until I explicitely close it. That makes viewing files too uncomfortable.

when I traverse NERDTree nodes I'd like to see the highlighted file content in a *temporary viewer buffer* and I'd like to explicitely select some of traversed files for editing, say by pressing *e*.

When I close NERDTree buffer, the *temporary viewer buffer* shall close as well, and there should only be opened buffers for those explicitely selected files, not for all viewed files.

Is that possible?

Comment: `netrw` has a "Preview" mapping (`p`) but it's not automatic and the preview window is not closed automatically. NERDTree doesn't do any of that: you'll have to write your own functions for all of that.

Comment: What you can do is cause it to be closed automatically with an `autocmd`, or you can at least close it with `:pclose` without the tedium of switching between windows.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like that could be a nice feature request for NERDTree :)

Meanwhile, you could put in your ~/.vimrc something like the following:

```
let g:nerd_preview_enabled = 0
let g:preview_last_buffer  = 0

function! NerdTreePreview()
  " Only on nerdtree window
  if (&ft ==# 'nerdtree')
    " Get filename
    let l:filename = substitute(getline("."), "^\\s\\+\\|\\s\\+$","","g")

    " Preview if it is not a folder
    let l:lastchar = strpart(l:filename, strlen(l:filename) - 1, 1)
    if (l:lastchar != "/" && strpart(l:filename, 0 ,2) != "..")

      let l:store_buffer_to_close = 1
      if (bufnr(l:filename) > 0)
        " Don't close if the buffer is already open
        let l:store_buffer_to_close = 0
      endif

      " Do preview
      execute "normal go"

      " Close previews buffer
      if (g:preview_last_buffer > 0)
        execute "bwipeout " . g:preview_last_buffer
        let g:preview_last_buffer = 0
      endif

      " Set last buffer to close it later
      if (l:store_buffer_to_close)
        let g:preview_last_buffer = bufnr(l:filename)
      endif
    endif
  elseif (g:preview_last_buffer > 0)
    " Close last previewed buffer
    let g:preview_last_buffer = 0
  endif
endfunction

function! NerdPreviewToggle()
  if (g:nerd_preview_enabled)
    let g:nerd_preview_enabled = 0
    augroup nerdpreview
      autocmd!
      augroup END
  else
    let g:nerd_preview_enabled = 1
    augroup nerdpreview
      autocmd!
      autocmd CursorMoved * nested call NerdTreePreview()
    augroup END
  endif
endfunction
```

This is probably quite naive and nasty code, but with some tweaking could do what you intend to do.

Edited, changes in version 2:

- Added nested on the autocommand so syntax highlight works
- Not enabled by default, execute :call NerdPreviewToggle() to enable/disable

Comment: That is cool!!! But preview buffer lost syntax highlighting. How can I enable syntax highlight for preview buffer?

Comment: Good point, just edited the answer to add the `nested` keyword that does it work properly (:help autocmd-nested)

Comment: Hmmm, yes, but looks like only previously opened files (existing buffers) are highlighted.

Comment: Just check it and seems to work in all the files :-\ :-/ Are you sure?

Comment: Also if I stay at the folder node and the second node in tree is the first file in that folder, then when I move cursor back and forth to the file and to the folder (if the file was not open explicitely the file) buffer closes every second time I put cursor on it.

In case the file was explicitely open then it is highlighted and the buffer doesn't close every second time cursor puts on the file node, which is the normal behavior

Answer (score 0):

I built on DavidEG's answer by taking tabs into account, because I ran into multiple nerdtree tab edge-cases.

```
function! PreviewNERDTreeFile()
  if !exists('t:previous_preview_buffer') | let t:previous_preview_buffer = 0 | endif
  let filename = substitute(getline('.'), '^\s*\|\s*$', '','g')
  let should_close_buffer_next_time = 1
  if (bufnr(filename) > 0) | let should_close_buffer_next_time = 0 | endif

  normal go
  if t:previous_preview_buffer > 0
    exe 'bwipeout ' . t:previous_preview_buffer
    let t:previous_preview_buffer = 0
  endif
  if should_close_buffer_next_time
    let t:previous_preview_buffer = bufnr(filename)
  endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a NERDTree extension that uses the last active buffer as a preview window, and either hijacks that window or splits it with the original content depending on if you open with `o, s, i, gs, gi` etc.

https://github.com/numEricL/nerdtree-live-preview